# Bash Script to fix domain list

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I know this will be really easy for one of you gurus!

I have a list like this:

```
 www.google.com
 ebay.com
 yahoo.com
 www.bing.com
 www.buy.com
 woot.com
 news.google.com
 images.google.com
```

I am trying to write a bash/sed/awk script to clean up this list.
I need the list to look like this:

```
 www.google.com
 www.ebay.com
 www.yahoo.com
 www.bing.com
 www.buy.com
 www.woot.com
 news.google.com
 images.google.com
```

In summary it needs to add "www." if it doesn't already have www or a sub-domain.  This list is in a file called theList.  My lame attempt is this:

```
 sed 's/^www\./' theList > cleanedList
```

That obviously doesn't work for the cases where it already has www or a sub-domain.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EV

Comment: What do you do with `foo.co.uk`? It needs a `www`, but how do you tell?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That's a valid question, but it's not part of the corpus. That's why I post a lot of comments asking for one: not every solution needs to cover every use case. Sometimes "quick and dirty" is good enough. :)

Comment: @CodeGnome: It's true, no such examples are listed. However, *we* don't know if there might be similar ones in the actual data. That's why *I* posted a comment asking about it. It may be that the OP is unaware that parsing domain names is a hard problem and thus didn't think to post a wider variety of examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier with awk than sed. For example:

```
awk -F. 'NF == 2 {print "www." $0; next}; {print}' theList > cleanedList
```

This defines "subdomains" as anything with less than two dots in the name, using the dot as the field separator within each record. You can certainly adjust this to suit.

It correctly handles the provided corpus, as you can see here:

```
$ cat cleanedList
www.google.com
www.ebay.com
www.yahoo.com
www.bing.com
www.buy.com
www.woot.com
news.google.com
images.google.com
```

Comment: hmmm...that looks good, except that it puts the www on domains that have sub domains (i.e. news.google.com and images.google.com).

Comment: @user548971 Good point; I think my awk solution is cleaner anyway. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can be shortened to `awk -F. 'NF==2 {print "www." $0; next}1' theList`

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can write this:

```
while read; do
  case "$REPLY" in
  www.*|*.*.*)         # begins with www. or contains at least two dots...
    echo "$REPLY"      # ...leave as-is
    ;;
  *)                   # all other cases...
    echo "www.$REPLY"  # ...prepend "www."
    ;;
  esac
done < theList > cleanedList
```

The outer while loop reads from stdin (redirected to `theList` in the last line), one line at a time. Without additional arguments, the line ends up in the shell variable `$REPLY`.

The case statement is like C's switch statement, but it compares against wildcard patterns instead of integral constants. We use it to classify the line (`$REPLY`) into two categories: one that needs no `www.` prepended, and the other that does.

The first pattern (`www.|*.*.*)`) is actually two alternatives: Either the line matches `www.*` (ie. starts with `www.`) or it matches `*.*.*` (ie. it contains at least two dots (they might be adjacent, but this it not a pattern to validate template names), because `*` in Unix matches also `.`s). In this case, we just output the line as we got it.

The second pattern (`*)`) matches everything, but it is only chosen if the first one didn't match. In these cases, we output `"www.$REPLY"`, ie. we add the `www.` to the line just read.

Together they implement the algorithm you described.

Answer (score 1):

The key is in [the regex](http://rubular.com/r/vNgCLb2rhy). It captures all standalone domains with no subdomain, then replaces it with `www.` and itself.

```
sed -ri 's/^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/www.\1/' YOUR_FILENAME
```

Alternatively:

```
sed -r 's/^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/www.\1/' YOUR_FILENAME > NEW_FILENAME
```

Comment: Why exclude `$`'s from the second part of the regexp? Remember the LHS of the regexp can be referenced by `&`, so `sed 's/^[^.]*\.[^.]*$/www.&/'` would work too and be a little less busy.

Comment: I don't understand why you would have `[^.]` as optional (`*`). It should be at least 1 or more (probably even 2, I've never seen a domain with 1 char). What reasons do you have for wanting me to not exclude `$`? Are you nitpicking just to nitpick?

Comment: Between `[` and `]`, `.` means a dot and `$` means a dollar. Outside of the class construct `.` means any character and `$` means end of string. So `[^.$]` means any character except a dot or a dollar, is this what your intended?

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent catch. Did not see that, thank you! :)